# Telebot Python + SQLite3

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am making a telegram bot that collects data into the sqlite3 database, there is a problem that I do not know how to solve. First, the bot collects user data, such as First Name, Last Name, Patronymic, group number, then buttons open to add personal achievements. So, after the user clicks the button for the first time, the user enters his achievement, and then when choosing another button, a bug pops up, how can I fix it? So that after the first time the user selects a button and adds one achievement, he can click another button again and add another achievement? Please help me.
Code:

```
# -*- coding: cp1251 -*- #перекодирование файла ради использования русского языка

import sqlite3
import telebot
from telebot import types

conn = sqlite3.connect("C:\\labs\\kursovaya\\PythonApplication1\\PythonApplication1\\db\\database.db",
                       check_same_thread=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()
global user_id
user_id=None

def db_table_val(user_id=None, user_name=None, user_surname=None, username=None, otchestvo=None, user_group=None,
                 nagrad_guap=None,
                 nagrad_region=None, nagrad_prochie=None, nagrad_premii_SPB=None):
    cursor.execute(
        'INSERT INTO test (user_id, user_name, user_surname, username, otchestvo, user_group, nagrad_guap, nagrad_region, nagrad_prochie, nagrad_premii_SPB) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
        (user_id, user_name, user_surname, username, otchestvo, user_group, nagrad_guap, nagrad_region, nagrad_prochie,
         nagrad_premii_SPB))
    conn.commit()


bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    global isPrivet
    isPrivet = False
    if not isPrivet:
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Привет! Напиши свое ФИО.</b>', parse_mode='html')
        u = message.chat.id
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_text_messages)
        isPrivet = True


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message1):
    global isRunning
    isRunning = False
    if not isRunning:
        mes = message1.text
        mes = mes.split()
        global us_id, us_name, username, us_sname, us_otch

        us_id = message1.chat.id
        us_name = message1.chat.first_name
        username = mes[0]
        us_sname = mes[1]
        us_otch = mes[2]

        msg = bot.send_message(message1.chat.id, 'Напишите Вашу группу')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_text_messages1)
        isRunning = True


def get_text_messages1(message2):
    group = message2.text
    db_table_val(us_id, us_name, username, us_sname, us_otch, group)
    conn.commit()
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message2, button)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['button'])
def button(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Награды ГУАП")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Награды региональные")
    item3 = types.KeyboardButton("Награды прочие")
    item4 = types.KeyboardButton("Премии Санкт-Петербурга")

    markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4)
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите какие Вы хотите достижения добавить?', reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, message_reply)


@bot.message_handler(state=11)
def message_reply(message3):
    if message3.text == "Награды ГУАП":
        bot.send_message(message3.chat.id, "Напишите, какие награды ГУАП Вы имеете")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message3, nagradi_guap)


    elif message3.text == "Награды региональные":
        bot.send_message(message3.chat.id, "Напишите, какие региональные Вы имеете")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message3, nagradi_reg)



    elif message3.text == "Награды прочие":
        bot.send_message(message3.chat.id, "Напишите, какие прочие награды Вы имеете")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message3, nagradi_prochie)


    elif message3.text == "Премии Санкт-Петербурга":
        bot.send_message(message3.chat.id, "Напишите, какие премии Санкт-Петербурга Вы имеете")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message3, premii_SPB)


@bot.message_handler(state=12)
def nagradi_guap(message):
    nagrad_guap = message.text
    sql_update_query = """Update test set nagrad_guap = ? where user_id = ?"""
    data = (nagrad_guap, us_id)
    cursor.execute(sql_update_query, data)
    conn.commit()


@bot.message_handler(state=13)
def nagradi_reg(message):
    nagrad_region = message.text
    sql_update_query = """Update test set nagrad_region = ? where user_id = ?"""
    data = (nagrad_region, us_id)
    cursor.execute(sql_update_query, data)
    conn.commit()


@bot.message_handler(state=14)
def nagradi_prochie(message):
    nagrad_prochie = message.text
    sql_update_query = """Update test set nagrad_prochie = ? where user_id = ?"""
    data = (nagrad_prochie, us_id)
    cursor.execute(sql_update_query, data)
    conn.commit()


@bot.message_handler(state=15)
def premii_SPB(message):
    nagrad_premii_SPB = message.text
    sql_update_query = """Update test set nagrad_premii_SPB = ? where user_id = ?"""
    data = (nagrad_premii_SPB, us_id)
    cursor.execute(sql_update_query, data)
    conn.commit()


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

I've tried various options with while true, but the bot just cycles, I don't know what to do anymore